# DB2 SPUFI query

Tags: db2

Using DB2 query, I need to fetch the address from Table A using multiple where condition and when the address is unknown in table A, I need to get the temporary address from Table B using multiple where condition from Both Table A and Table B.

The common field for both the table is Employee ID

Where condition should be,

```
A.Emp-dept = xxx
A.Emp-state = yyy
B.Emp-code = zzz
B.Emp-proj = AAA
```

I Tried the below query

```
SELECT A.EMP_ID
A.EMP_ADDR,
A.EMP_DEPT,
B.EMP_CODE,
B.EMP_TEMP_ADDR
FROM TAB A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB B
ON A.EMP_ID = B.EMP_ID
WHERE A.Emp_dept = xxx
A.Emp_state = yyy
B.Emp_code = zzz
B.Emp_proj = AAA
ORDER BY EMP_ID
```

But this query is not working, I am getting 0 rows as result

Expected Result

https://dbfiddle.uk/s7zr35wU

Comment: You should provide some fully reproducible example with sample data and the result desired on it. You may edit sample data at the [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/rIv60X0U) as needed, post your own link (when you edit contents and press "Run" it changes) here, edit your question with the same query as at the link, and show the result desired.

Comment: Yes, I have added the Expected result link @MarkBarinstein

Comment: The expectation was that you don't touch sample data and show the expected result in a table form, not as a result of the query. It's not clear how I can help otherwise...

Comment: Guessing: is [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/jFX9-Mn3) what you need?

Answer (score 0):

If there may or may not be a row in table B, then you need to put the filter in the `ON` clause instead of the `WHERE`. With it in the `WHERE`, you are basically treating table B as an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN because it is joining the two tables together with the ON criteria, and then filtering it out with the WHERE criteria.

You need something like this:

```sql
SELECT A.EMP_ID
A.EMP_ADDR,
A.EMP_DEPT,
B.EMP_CODE,
B.EMP_TEMP_ADDR
FROM TAB A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB B
  ON A.EMP_ID = B.EMP_ID
 AND B.Emp_code = zzz
 AND B.Emp_proj = AAA
WHERE A.Emp_dept = xxx
  AND A.Emp_state = yyy
ORDER BY EMP_ID
```

This assumes that you are at least going to get a row from table A (with a NULL address or something). If that is not the case, you may need to use [FULL OUTER JOIN](https://www.ibm.com/docs/de/db2-for-zos/12?topic=table-full-outer-join) instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: I need to fetch a TEMP_ADDR from TAB B only when ADDR in TAB A value is 'UNKWN'.                                                                                                                              
@bhamby SELECT A.EMP_ID A.EMP_ADDR, A.EMP_DEPT, B.EMP_CODE, B.EMP_TEMP_ADDR FROM TAB A LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB B ON A.EMP_ID = B.EMP_ID AND A.ADDR = 'UNKWN' AND B.Emp_code = zzz AND B.Emp_proj = AAA WHERE A.Emp_dept = xxx AND A.Emp_state = yyy ORDER BY EMP_ID                                                                                             Will this query work?